# $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } x^n\cos(2\pi nx)$, $x \in [-1,1]$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions defined as follows:

$f_n(x)=x^n\cos(2\pi nx)$, $x \in [-1,1]$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty  }   f_n(x)$ exists if and only if x belongs to the interval

(a) (-1,1)

(b) [-1,1)

(c) [0,1]

(d)  (-1,1]

Clearly, the limit exists for $x=1$ and doesn't exist for $x=-1$, so according to me answer should be (d).

Comment: You are right. I have added an answer explaining some of the details involved.

Comment: @VikasSharma Next time that you post a question, please avoid titles that are mathematical expressions or equations only. These are discouraged for technical reasons - see the second item of [Guidelines for good use of $\rm\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Answer (score 1):

We have to look at $$\lim_{n\to\infty} x^n \cos (2\pi nx)$$
where $n\in \mathbb N$.

1. Take $x = 1$. $$\lim_{n\to\infty} x^n \cos (2\pi nx) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \cos (2\pi n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \cos 0 = 1 \quad (x = 1)$$
2. Take $x\in (-1,1)$. Then,
   $$|x^n \cos (2\pi nx)| \le |x|^n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$$
   giving $$\lim_{n\to\infty} x^n \cos (2\pi nx) = 0 \quad (-1 < x  < 1)$$
3. Lastly, consider $x = -1$. $$\lim_{n\to\infty} x^n \cos (2\pi nx) = \lim_{n\to\infty} (-1)^n \cos (-2\pi n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} (-1)^n$$
   which does not exist.

This gives option (d), i.e. $(-1,1]$.

Comment: How does the limit exist at $x=1$ when the left hand limit $\neq$ value of function at that point?

Comment: @RiverX15 No one said that for a limit to exist it has to equal the value of the function at that point. That happens for continuous functions. Take $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x & x\ne 0\\ 1 & x = 0 \end{cases}$$ which is discontinuous, and observe that the limit at $0$ exists even though it isn't equal to $f(0)$.

Comment: Oh no I confused it with continuity. Thanks for the clarification!